# How is running printf changing values in my int variables?

Tags: c, gcc

I'm coding in C for the first time for a class, using gcc as my compiler.

I would like to apologize in advance for being the 10,000,000th person to ask this question.

For those not interested in reading all of this, I have emboldened the actual question (the last paragraph) below.

My code is copied at the end of this question. I turned the assignment in with only a 10 int array, and the sort works correctly, but if I change it to an 11 length array, things get weird. For this question, I'm talking about how my code functions with an array of 11 numbers to be sorted.

I'm experiencing an issue which I believe to have to do with poorly written code dealing with memory in an unpredictable/incorrect way. I found many stackoverflow questions with a similar problem, but after all my troubleshooting and searching I am still stuck. None of the questions I found had solutions that fixed my problem.  I also believe it's likely that my algorithm for merge sort is flawed and might be causing the problem, but I have not yet picked out what exactly I did wrong, as it works correctly sometimes.

Most of the S.O. questions I looked at had to deal with passing a function scope address back out to a calling function, or declared-but-uninitialized variables. I have looked through my code and not found any instances of either of these issues, but I believe my issue to be of a similar nature.

**If I add a printf(" "); statement anywhere into my `merge()` function definition, the code sorts the array correctly.  The `printf` statement has to actually have at least one character in it, and has no effect if I put it in any other functions. What am I doing wrong in the code below that's allowing a simple call to printf to change the values being passed around by my functions?**

Note:  I have compiled this in a linux environment with GCC as well as on windows with MinGW GCC, it performs differently in each situation, but in both situations it is broken and appears to be the same issue.

The code for my simple merge sort implementation is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NUMVALS 11

//function prototypes
void printArrValues(int*, int);
void mergeSort(int*, int, int);
void merge(int*, int, int, int, int);
void showArraySorting(int*);

//define some data to sort
int intArrValsDesc[NUMVALS]    = {10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0};
int intArrValsAsc[NUMVALS]     = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11};
int intArrValsPreset1[NUMVALS] = {6,6,2,2,1,1,6,2,1,1,4};
int intArrValsPreset2[NUMVALS] = {13,99,23,1,57,29,19,456,9,9,34};

//self explanatory
int main() {
    //show a few different sorting scenarios    
    //showArraySorting(intArrValsAsc);
    //showArraySorting(intArrValsDesc);
    //showArraySorting(intArrValsPreset1);
    showArraySorting(intArrValsPreset2);

    return(0);
} 

/*
** function to sort array while outputting beginning state, 
** progress states, and finished state
*/
void showArraySorting(int *intArrToSort) {       
    //output initial array values
    printf("Start: ");
    printArrValues(intArrToSort, NUMVALS);

    mergeSort(intArrToSort, 0, NUMVALS - 1);

    //output sorted array values
    printf("Finish: ");
    printArrValues(intArrToSort, NUMVALS);
    printf("-----------------\n");       
}

/*
** function to output each value in the argument int array to the 
** console in the current order via stdio in the format "[ a b c ... ]"
*/
void printArrValues(int *intArrToPrint, int intNumValues) {

    //define iteration counter int for looping through the values array
    int i;

    //begin the line with bracket for aesthetics
    printf("[ ");

    //loop MAX times to print out the values 
    for (i = 0; i < intNumValues; i++) {

        //print out each value with a space after it
        printf("%d ", intArrToPrint[i]);
    }

    //end the line with closing bracket 
    printf("]\n");
}

//function which implements the merge sort algorithm 
//by keeping track of nested index ranges in the array to be sorted.
//as sorting decisions are made, numbers are rearranged in the target array
void mergeSort(int *intArrToSort, int intLeftStartIndex, int intRightEndIndex) {        
    //if the current index range hasn't yet honed down to a single index
    if (intLeftStartIndex < intRightEndIndex) {
        //printf("\n");
        //find the remaining two indices required to split the argument index
        //range into two smaller ones
        int intLeftEndIndex = (intLeftStartIndex + intRightEndIndex) / 2;
        int intRightStartIndex = intLeftEndIndex + 1;

        //printf("[%d, %d] and [%d, %d]\n",intLeftStartIndex,intLeftEndIndex, intRightStartIndex, intRightEndIndex);

        //continue recursively breaking the array subsets down into smaller pieces
        mergeSort(intArrToSort, intLeftStartIndex, intLeftEndIndex);
        mergeSort(intArrToSort, intRightStartIndex, intRightEndIndex);

        //all recursion below this level has finished, so merge the current two array subsets
        merge(intArrToSort, intLeftStartIndex, intLeftEndIndex, intRightStartIndex, intRightEndIndex);
        //show the status of the sort
        printf("  sorting... ");
        printArrValues(intArrToSort, NUMVALS);
    }        
}

/*
** Function to re-order the broken down components of the merge sort
** by comparing them to each other and swapping values in the parent array.
*/
void merge(int *intArrToSort, int intLeftStartIndex, int intLeftEndIndex, int intRightStartIndex, int intRightEndIndex) {

    //calculate and store the number of values in each subset of the array.
    int intLeftArrSize = intLeftEndIndex - intLeftStartIndex + 1;
    int intRightArrSize = intRightEndIndex - intRightStartIndex + 1;

    //keep track of the total number of ints being combined in this pass
    int intTotalSize = intRightEndIndex - intLeftStartIndex + 1;

    //create new arrays to stack the sorted values in
    int intArrLeft[intLeftArrSize], intArrRight[intRightArrSize];
    int i;      

    //copy values into new left array
    for (i = 0; i < intLeftArrSize; i++) {
        intArrLeft[i] = intArrToSort[intLeftStartIndex + i];
    }
    //copy values into new right array
    for (i = 0; i < intRightArrSize; i++) {        
        intArrRight[i] = intArrToSort[intRightStartIndex + i];
    }

    //define the ints to hold the current index for both the left
    //and right array subsets. 
    int intCurrentLeftIndex = 0;
    int intCurrentRightIndex = 0;

    //define the int to hold the "target" index, initialize it with the leftmost
    //index of the left array subset. this holds which position in intArrToSort
    //is about to be updated with a new, sorted value 
    int intTargetIndex = intLeftStartIndex;    

    //sentinel variable for while loop
    int intDone = 0;

    //loop until all numbers in the two array subsets have been sorted into intArrToSort
    while (intDone == 0) {        
        //check if the lowest uncombined value in the left array is lower than the one in the right array
        if (intArrLeft[intCurrentLeftIndex] <= intArrRight[intCurrentRightIndex]) {
            //it is, so assign it to the current target position in the combined array
            intArrToSort[intTargetIndex] = intArrLeft[intCurrentLeftIndex];

            //increment the array's index counter to signal that another number has been combined
            intCurrentLeftIndex++;

            //check if the lowest uncombined value in the right array is lower than the one in the left array
        } else {

            //it is, so assign it to the current target position in the combined array
            intArrToSort[intTargetIndex] = intArrRight[intCurrentRightIndex];

            //increment the array's index counter to signal that another number has been combined
            intCurrentRightIndex++;
        }       

        //increment the target index to prevent overwriting the recently combined value
        intTargetIndex++;

        //if we've combined all but one item in the two array subsets 
        if (intCurrentLeftIndex + intCurrentRightIndex >= intTotalSize - 1) {

            //don't iterate again through this while loop
            intDone = 1;

            //if the remaining item is in the left array
            if (intLeftArrSize - intCurrentLeftIndex > 0) {

                //copy its value to intArrToSort
                intArrToSort[intTargetIndex] = intArrLeft[intCurrentLeftIndex];

                //if the remaining item isn't in the left array
            } else {

                //assume it's in the right array and copy its value to intArrToSort
                intArrToSort[intTargetIndex] = intArrRight[intCurrentRightIndex];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also welcome any related or unrelated criticism of my terrible code.

Comment: Have you tried step through the function with a debugger?

Comment: Run your code through [valgrind](http://valgrind.org).  You may be surprised at what you find.

Comment: This is UB for sure.

Comment: I did try GDBing this code, I'm new to doing that, I could not figure out the issue, only that the issue was likely in my merge function.

Also, I saw Valgrind recommended elsewhere and I should have used it before asking this question. I used it and it confirmed that the issue was in my merge function and told me that it was, in fact, uninitialized values.  This didn't make it clear to me what was wrong, but led me to look into C arrays more closely at which point I realized I was a complete moron.

Comment: ' at which point I realized I was a complete moron' - OK, I removed my downvote in the face of such unusual honesty :)

Comment: When adding a printf changes the behavior, the problem is usually an uninitialized variable.

Comment: @SteveSummit Yes, that's what I kept seeing, but I misunderstood how array creation worked. I thought that since I was setting `array[i] = someValue;` in a for loop right after `int array[sizeOfArray];`, that was the same as "initializing the array".  My arrays were created with a variable for the length and I don't think this was working as I thought it was.

Comment: Update:  My dynamic and uninitialized arrays don't actually seem to have been the problem, even though Valgrind complained about them. Since my for loops were assigning every value in those arrays before they got used, they were alright. My merge sort algorithm was just terribly botched and resulted in periodically reading memory outside of said arrays.

Comment: @SteveSummit in this case it turned out to be reading off the end of a local array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in the `merge` function: your test for termination is incorrect, you assume that your only need to check the last element.  In fact, you need to check if you are done with each half to stop comparing elements once this happens.  Imagine for instance that the array is already sorted: the left half will be copied completely and your test will fail to detect that you cannot compare the next element from the left with the first from the right half.

Here is a corrected version:

```
/*
** Function to re-order the broken down components of the merge sort
** by comparing them to each other and swapping values in the parent array.
*/
void merge(int *intArrToSort, int intLeftStartIndex, int intLeftEndIndex, int intRightStartIndex, int intRightEndIndex) {

    //calculate and store the number of values in each subset of the array.
    int intLeftArrSize = intLeftEndIndex - intLeftStartIndex + 1;
    int intRightArrSize = intRightEndIndex - intRightStartIndex + 1;

    //keep track of the total number of ints being combined in this pass
    int intTotalSize = intRightEndIndex - intLeftStartIndex + 1;

    //create new arrays to stack the sorted values in
    int intArrLeft[intLeftArrSize], intArrRight[intRightArrSize];
    int i;      

    //copy values into new left array
    for (i = 0; i < intLeftArrSize; i++) {
        intArrLeft[i] = intArrToSort[intLeftStartIndex + i];
    }
    //copy values into new right array
    for (i = 0; i < intRightArrSize; i++) {        
        intArrRight[i] = intArrToSort[intRightStartIndex + i];
    }

    //define the ints to hold the current index for both the left
    //and right array subsets. 
    int intCurrentLeftIndex = 0;
    int intCurrentRightIndex = 0;

    //using i to index into the destination array receiving the merged elements
    //loop until while there elements left in both arrays
    for (i = intLeftStartIndex; intCurrentLeftIndex < intLeftArrSize && intCurrentRightIndex < intRightArrSize; i++) {        
        //check if the lowest uncombined value in the left array is lower than the one in the right array
        if (intArrLeft[intCurrentLeftIndex] <= intArrRight[intCurrentRightIndex]) {
            //if so, assign it to the current target position in the combined array
            intArrToSort[i] = intArrLeft[intCurrentLeftIndex];

            //increment the array's index counter
            intCurrentLeftIndex++;
        } else {
             //otherwise, assign the element from the right array to the current target position in the combined array
            intArrToSort[intTargetIndex] = intArrRight[intCurrentRightIndex];

            //and increment the array's index counter
            intCurrentRightIndex++;
        } 
    }

    //we have exhausted either the left or the right half:

    // try and copy left over elements from the left    
    for (; intCurrentLeftIndex < intLeftArrSize; i++) {            
        intArrToSort[i] = intArrLeft[intCurrentLeftIndex];
        intCurrentLeftIndex++;
    }

    // and finally try and copy left over elements from the right    
    for (; intCurrentRightIndex < intRightArrSize; i++) {            
        intArrToSort[i] = intArrRight[intCurrentRightIndex];
        intCurrentRightIndex++;
    }
}
```

As for criticizing your code constructively:

- There are far too many comments, the code is buried in useless verbiage that comment obvious statements.
- The variable names are way too long. Choose meaningful, but short names.  An array index that is used in a simple `for` loop with obvious bounds can be named `i`, `j` or `k`.
- The array boundaries should follow the C conventions, first is included, last is excluded.  This makes the code much simpler and allows for an empty array.
- Prototypes for forward function declarations should have argument names for easier reading.

Here is a simplified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NUMVALS 11

//function prototypes
void printArrValues(int *array, int length);
void mergeSort(int *array, int start, int end);
void merge(int *array, int start, int middle, int end);
void showArraySorting(int *array);

//define some data to sort
static int intArrValsDesc[NUMVALS]    = { 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0 };
static int intArrValsAsc[NUMVALS]     = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 };
static int intArrValsPreset1[NUMVALS] = { 6, 6, 2, 2, 1, 1, 6, 2, 1, 1, 4 };
static int intArrValsPreset2[NUMVALS] = { 13, 99, 23, 1, 57, 29, 19, 456, 9, 9, 34 };

int main(void) {
    //show a few different sorting scenarios    
    showArraySorting(intArrValsAsc);
    showArraySorting(intArrValsDesc);
    showArraySorting(intArrValsPreset1);
    showArraySorting(intArrValsPreset2);
    return 0;
} 

/*
 ** function to sort array while outputting beginning state,
 ** progress states, and finished state.
 */
void showArraySorting(int *array) {
    printf("Start: ");
    printArrValues(array, NUMVALS);
    mergeSort(array, 0, NUMVALS);
    printf("Finish: ");
    printArrValues(array, NUMVALS);
    printf("-----------------\n");
}

/*
 ** function to output each value in the argument int array to the 
 ** console in the current order via stdio in the format "[ a b c ... ]"
 */
void printArrValues(int *array, int length) {
    printf("[ ");
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        printf("%d ", array[i]);
    }
    printf("]\n");
}

/*
 ** function which implements the merge sort algorithm
 ** by keeping track of nested index ranges in the array to be sorted.
 ** as sorting decisions are made, numbers are rearranged in the target array
 */
void mergeSort(int *array, int start, int end) {
    //if the current index range hasn't yet honed down to a single index
    if (end - start > 1) {
        int middle = (start + end) / 2;

        //continue recursively breaking the array subsets down into smaller pieces
        mergeSort(array, start, middle);
        mergeSort(array, middle, end);

        //all recursion below this level has finished, so merge the current two array subsets
        merge(array, start, middle, end);
    }
}

/*
 ** function to merge adjacent sorted array slices
 */
void merge(int *array, int start, int middle, int end) {
    //calculate and store the number of values in each subset of the array.
    int leftSize = middle - start;
    int rightSize = end - middle;

    //define temporary arrays to hold values as the destination will be overwritten
    int leftArray[leftSize], rightArray[rightSize];
    int i;      

    //copy values into new left array
    for (i = 0; i < leftSize; i++) {
        leftArray[i] = array[start + i];
    }
    //copy values into new right array
    for (i = 0; i < rightSize; i++) {        
        rightArray[i] = array[middle + i];
    }

    int leftIndex = 0;
    int rightIndex = 0;

    //using i to index into the destination array receiving the merged elements
    //loop until while there elements left in both arrays
    for (i = start; leftIndex < leftSize && rightIndex < rightSize; i++) {
        if (leftArray[leftIndex] <= rightArray[rightIndex]) {
            array[i] = leftArray[leftIndex];
            leftIndex++;
        } else {
            array[i] = rightArray[rightIndex];
            rightIndex++;
        } 
    }

    // try and copy left over elements from the left array
    for (; leftIndex < leftSize; i++) {
        array[i] = leftArray[leftIndex];
        leftIndex++;
    }

    // and finally try and copy left over elements from the right array
    for (; rightIndex < rightSize; i++) {
        array[i] = rightArray[rightIndex];
        rightIndex++;
    }
}
```

Note the allocating the temporary arrays in automatic storage (*on the stack*) is not recommended for large amounts of data.  You could instead allocate a temporary working array with `malloc` at the top level and pass that to both the recursive function and the `merge` function.  Actually, the `merge` function does not need to be a separate function.

Here is an implementation of this, where `mergeSort` just takes the array and its length:

```
/*
 ** recursive function implement the merge sort algorithm.
 */
static void mergeSortHelper(int *array, int *temp, int start, int end) {
    if (end - start > 1) {
        int i, middle = (start + end) / 2;

        mergeSortHelper(array, temp, start, middle);
        mergeSortHelper(array, temp, middle, end);

        /* copy both subarrays in a single loop */
        for (i = start; i < end; i++) {
            temp[i] = array[i];
        }
        /* merge subarrays */
        int left = start;
        int right = middle;
        for (i = start; left < middle && right < end; i++) {
            if (temp[left] <= temp[right])
                array[i] = temp[left++];
            else
                array[i] = temp[right++];
        }
        /* flush left subarray */
        while (left < middle) {
            array[i++] = temp[left++];
        }
        /* no need to flush right subarray, elements are already in place */
    }
}

/*
 ** function which implements the merge sort algorithm
 ** by keeping track of nested index ranges in the array to be sorted.
 ** as sorting decisions are made, numbers are rearranged in the target array
 */
void mergeSort(int *array, int length) {
    if (length < 2) {
        return;
    } else
    if (length <= 1000) {
        int temp[1000];
        mergeSortHelper(array, temp, 0, length);
    } else {
        int *temp = malloc(length * sizeof(int));
        if (!temp) {
            printf("not enough memory for mergeSort\n");
            return;
        }
        mergeSortHelper(array, temp, 0, length);
        free(temp);
    }
}
```

Comment: I had gotten to this point after fixing my uninitialized variable warnings and realizing that wasn't the problem.  Thank you for looking through and finding that.  I was going to answer it myself but I'm glad someone else did.

Comment: Yeah the comments are me playing it safe for my class because they take points away if you don't comment enough.  (I turned this assignment in last week so I'm not using S.O. to cheat.) I know it's overkill, as are many of the variable names.  I do really like having the data type in the variable name though.

Comment: @BumbleShrimp:  I understand, but overcommenting is counterproductive, as is using overlong local variable names.  Your code was so overcrowded, that nobody answered the question or even looked into it to find the bug because IMHO, they were rebuffed by the verbosity.

Comment: @BumbleShrimp: you might want to study my last edit, using a shared array for temporary storage simplifies the code a lot and allows for much larger arrays to be sorted.

Comment: @BumbleShrimp Putting the type in the variable name is generally not a good idea.  If you ever change the type (ex. from `int` to `long`), you need to change the name everywhere it's referenced.

Comment: @BumbleShrimp: as a matter of fact, the type should be `size_t`.  With my latest addition, the array could be longer than `INT_MAX`.  Plus dividing an `int` by 2 generates more code than dividing an unsigned integer by 2.  adding the type in the variable name obscures its actual meaning.  No need to do this for local indices in small functions.  Your teacher may impose this rule, so abide by it, but it is not a good rule IMHO.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback everyone, and sorry for the bloated code.